# how to remove small space between navbar and content in ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm developing a ionic application, I set the content background to be an image, however there is a small space between the navbar and the content:
[image]

the html (with some of the css):
[image]

I can't find the cause of the small blank space, any help is appreciated

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can't really add an MCVE because I could not pinpoint the error in all of the ionic css classes involved, problem was too broad, that is why I added some screenshots.

Comment: Is that a gap or a border? Did you try setting `border-bottom-width` to 0?

Comment: already found the problem, please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, somehow the ionic guys appear to have set the background size to get a border, which is weird to say the least, anyways:

```
.bar-header {
    background-size: 0;
}
```

Fixes it.